# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, babeljs

I'm using React with Redux and I'm having troubles with IE. Only on IE doesn't work.

When I build app with only react it works, so I'm guessing it's something with Redux. It is returning undefined for app and redux-logger is showing this error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

My webpack:

```
const path = require("path");
const componentName = "contact-captain";
const publicFolderRelativePath = "../../../../public/js";
module.exports = {
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, publicFolderRelativePath),
        filename: `${componentName}.js`
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack -w --mode development --progress --color --display-error-details",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.22.2"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"]
}
```

It works when I use babel-polyfill, but I can't use it because on the page where this is loading babel-polyfill is already used so it's returning errors for that different component.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this helped me

```
  if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
        Object.assign = function(target) {
            'use strict';
            if (target == null) {
                throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
            }

            target = Object(target);
            for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
                var source = arguments[index];
                if (source != null) {
                    for (var key in source) {
                        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
                            target[key] = source[key];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return target;
        };
    }
```

Comment: This solution also solves the error IE11 throws when loading a page that has Facebook chat plugin. After adding your code, the FB chat started working on IE. Thank you @olga_babic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-assign to your .babelrc in order to make it working